# Reading files from an EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

It seems that the Java EE specification doesn't allow to read files from an EJB, as stated clearly on the next link:

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/qanda/ejb_tier/restrictions.html#file_access

It says:

> Enterprise beans aren't allowed to access files primarily because files are not transactional resources. Allowing EJBs to access files or directories in the filesystem, or to use file descriptors, would compromise component distributability, and would be a security hazard.

How then am I supposed to read from a file in an Application server?

Comment: Not everything in an Application server is an EJB.

Comment: That is being downgraded to a recommendation in EJB 3.2.  The risk of "hurting yourself" applies to all code running in the server. There's nothing specific about EJBs that makes it less safe or safer elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with all the points that are against such an operation, well explained in the link you have cited. The link also suggests the preferred way to access business data, i.e. through a JDBC interface.

However, using GlassFish I am able to open and read a file residing in the web folder, from within a `@Stateless` `@EJB` and also from an `@ApplicationScoped` `CDI` Bean. I use `ClassLoader` for that purpose:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ClassLoader loader = LicenseMessage.class.getClassLoader(); 
        InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream("../../resources/myFile.txt");
    }
}
```