# Access files stored in a web content folder from an EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, webcontent

I have some data files in my WebApplication which I want to read.

How can I access them from an EJB?

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
@Singleton
public class Server {

  public void loadData() {
    InputStream is =
      this.getClass().getClassLoader().
      getResourceAsStream("WebContent/WEB-INF/Data/Data.xml");
    //read from is...
  }

}
```

Or is there any better way to handle read-only data files? I don't want to use a database, because I never have to write into these files, and I can parse big XML files very easily.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading files from an EJB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735221/reading-files-from-an-ejb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting, I finally got it working.
The Problem was the wrong Path. Right is:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../Data/Data.xml");
```

(I don't know why)...

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("classpath:Data/Data.xml");
```

is not working for me but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
public void loadData() {
  InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("classpath:Data/Data.xml");
  //read from is...
}
```

More details here: [URL to load resources from the classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java)